# How to measure heavy water concentration?

Tags: water, isotopes

regular tap water contains small %   D2O , let say a distillation process remove small amount of H2O . how can one measure this change using tools available to average person.

Comment: Could you supply a source for the percentage of heavy water in ordinary tap water?

Comment: @DJohnM : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water

Comment: _tools available to [the] average person_?  This proably is available to the average person-who-has-the-cash.  http://www.perkinelmer.com/Catalog/Family/ID/Clarus%20600%20Gas%20ChromatographMass%20Spectrometer?gclid=CKe1osH8tccCFdIXHwodBqAKwQ

Comment: @jameslarge , how about light index , or adding a fish to the container?

Comment: I don't know about the refractive index of heavy water, but I seriously doubt that a fish will give you a useful _quantitative_ measure.  (That _is_ what you asked for---how can one _measure_ this change.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from $D_2O$ (heavy water), natural water also contains $HDO$ (semi-heavy water) and of course $H_2O$.

The physical properties of these substances do vary from one to another, as can be seen from [this Wikipedia comparative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water#Physical_properties_.28with_comparison_to_light_water.29). For example, the melting point of $D_2O$ differs sufficiently from that of $HHO$ or $H_2O$ to be measurable by a hobbyist or amateur scientist.

The problem is that deuterium ($D$) has very low natural abundance: only 1 in 6420 hydrogen atoms is deuterium (in the world's oceans), [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium).

At such low abundance of $D_2O$ and $HHO$ the influence of these substances on the bulk properties of tap water is beyond reasonable means of measurement by an "average person". And a single electrolysis has only a small effect on these low abundances.

The same is true on the effect such low abundances (and any small changes thereof) on biological systems, even though much higher concentrations of $D$ does have a strong negative effect on the metabolism of most animals (like fish).

Comment: HHO semi-heavy ?

Comment: perhaps DHO , or H-O-D

Comment: HDO of course, not HHO. A typo that's been corrected. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

In "ordinary" water, about 156 out of 1,000,000 hydrogen atoms are deuterium.

If you were to pick any instant in time, these atoms would be arranged in water molecules as follows:$$HHO---0.999688024$$ $$HDO---0.000311951$$ $$DDO---0.000000024$$
So only about 24 molecules of true heavy water exist in a billion molecules of ordinary water.

In addition, these hydrogen and deuterium atoms are rapidly exchanged in water.  If you were to watch a particular one of the tiny number of $D_2O$ molecules, (don't ask me how) you would see the D atoms swapped out (and possibly back in again)
very quickly.

I don't know any "kitchen-sink" method to detect the effect of removing a few of the super abundant H atoms...

Comment: how about tritium ?  is high concentration of DDO generates it ? or it naturally exists.

Comment: @michael501 Tritium decays fairly quickly (12.3 years half life), so in nature, there's essentially no Tritium to speak of in oceans or tap water.   It's essentially a man made element, though stars might have tiny amounts of it, but the short half life keeps it from being present in nature.